NextJS how to display fetched data depending on date now
I'm new to nextJS and frontend technologies.
I am facing a problem. I am trying to display some concerts data in two separate lists depending if they are to come or passed.
When a visitor would come to this page it should take the page load date and create the two lists.
I tried loading my component server side but it always keeps the server date (normal behaviour).
Then I tried to turn my component to client side. But I couldn't fetch my data.
There is my actual code if it can help. This component is then used in a server side page.
"use client";

import { getConcerts } from "@/lib/api";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function Counter() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date());
  const [concert, setConcerts] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      // Mettre à jour la date toutes les secondes
      setDate(new Date());
    }, 1000);

    const fetchData = async () => {
      setConcerts(await getConcerts());
    };

    fetchData();

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>Click me</button>
      <p>{date.toLocaleString()}</p>{" "}
      {/* Convertir la date en une chaîne de texte lisible */}
    </div>
  );
}

And the code for that fetches the data
export async function getConcerts(): Promise<any> {
  const entry = await fetchGraphQL(
    `query {
      concertCollection {
        items {
          sys {id }
          titre
          evenement
          date
          information {
            json
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)
  return extractConcerts(entry);
}

function extractConcerts(fetchResponse: any): any {
  const concerts = fetchResponse?.data?.concertCollection?.items ?? [];
  return concerts;
}


Please add the code for getConcerts(). Are you trying to refresh data after certain interval ?

I've updated the initial subject. Below, you'll find the code for 'getConcert.' Essentially, it's a GraphQL query that retrieves data from a headless CMS. My objective is to obtain the current date upon page load and subsequently categorize my concerts into two lists: 'past' and 'future'.

Please also add the dummy data (format) of data returned by getConcerts().
